# Making concurrent request with different id after a delay

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make a GET request using the user_id key which I get from userData object.

For making the request

var userData = [
        {
        id: 1,
        user_id: '1234',
        },
       {
        id: 2,
        user_id: '123454',
        },
         .
         .
         900 enteries
    ]

*abc.com?user_id = 1234*

delay of 6s

*abc.com?user_id = 123454*

next request delay of 6s
...........

with consecutive user_id after an interval, I am using the setInterval function but when making a request the user_id is not fetched in the same order.

**How can this be achieved?**

```
function checkStatus(userData) {
    userData.map(function(n) {
        var requestLoop = setInterval(function() {
            request({
                url: "abc.com?user_id="n.user_id,
                n.user_id,
                method: "GET"
            }, function(error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    return error;
                }
            });
        }, 60000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you starting a `setInterval()` inside a loop which means you'll have a whole bunch of them running.

Comment: Ill close with clearInterval(requestLoop) @jfriend00.But how to achieve  Making concurrent request with different id after a delay?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do.  This code is clearly wrong as you will have a whole bunch of `setInterval()` timers that run forever.  If you want me to help, you'll have to do a better job explaining what you're trying to accomplish as I don't currently understand.

Comment: i want to make requests
var userData = [ { id: 1, user_id: '1234', }, { id: 2, user_id: '123454', }, . . 900 enteries ]



abc.com?user_id = 1234,

abc.com?user_id = 1235
and each request should be made with a delay.
@jfriend00

Comment: What are you trying to do with the results?

Comment: Nothing to do with results just want to know status of each get request @jfriend00

Comment: You must be wanting to do something with the results.  Are you trying to collect all the result in an array and then do something when they're all done?  Or are you acting on them as you get each one?  This determines how to structure the code.

Comment: i want to check status for each request @jfriend00

Comment: What does check status mean?  I could help you in a few minutes if I understand what you're really trying to do.

Comment: check if the status is 200 for each  get request  otherwise send mail for each request whose mail is not on (this email part i can do this myself).@jfriend00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty ways to do what you want to do. THe real question is, what do you want to do?

#### 1. For each entry in `userData`, run a `GET` request, but only after a delay of `6 secs` after the previous request.

```
function query(n) {
    request({
        url: "abc.com?user_id=" + n.user_id,
        n.user_id,
        method: "GET"
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            return error;
        }
    });
}

userData.forEach(function (n, i) {
    setTimeout(query, 6000 * i, n);
});
```

#### 2. For each entry in `userData`, run *multiple* `GET` requests, each after a delay of 6 secs after the previous request.

```
function query(n) {
    request({
        url: "abc.com?user_id=" + n.user_id,
        n.user_id,
        method: "GET"
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            return error;
        }

        // ...

        if (shouldRepeatCondition) {
            // keep repeating
            setTimeout(query, 6000, n);
        }
    });
}

userData.forEach(function (n, i) {
    setTimeout(query, 6000 * i, n);
})
```